# Retrieve the UPS Account number of a customer in Magento API

Tags: magento

In Magento, a customer can associate an UPS Account # with their account allowing them to ship and pay for their shipments with their personal UPS account number.

I'm in need of retrieving that on an order or customer basis via the Magento API (V2). Does anyone know if that is data that can be pulled via the V2 API? I'm trying to avoid hitting the Magento DB directly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That information is in a System Config (`Mage::getStoreConfig()`). I don't think the API gives you access to system configurations, you're going to have to get them using code:

```
$userid      = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/ups/username');
$userid_pass = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/ups/password');
$access_key  = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/ups/access_license_number');
```

Good luck.

***EDIT*** based on comment:

So if you have the Customer object (`$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);` you can do `$customer->getShippingAccount();` (or whatever the attribute is called). You don't want to be querying the varchar table directly. If you're looping through customers you would do

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('shipping_account')
    ;
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean the shipping account number of an individual customer. It's stored as a customer attribute in the customer_entity_varchar table. After looking into it some more, I don't beleive this is an "out-of-the-box" attribute and was added at one point with an extension or plugin. In our system, this value has an attribute ID of 1012.